# Angularjs rootscope value is undefined within the same controller in same function

Tags: angularjs

I have set the username value in rootscope and when I try to use it within the same function it becomes undefined. I am not sure why this is happening.

controller

```
    xxxApp.controller('listController', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, $log, uiGridConstants, $rootScope) {

        $scope.isSelected = false;
        $scope.showSpinner = true;
        $rootScope.loggedInUser = {};



        $scope.user = {};
        $http.get("/mdm/getLoggedInUsername")
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {              
                    $scope.user = data.user;                
                    $rootScope.loggedInUser = $scope.user;
                    console.log("the logged in user is 1" +$scope.user);

                    console.log("the rootscope logged in user is 1" +$rootScope.loggedInUser);
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
                    console.log("Error ....the logged in user is 1" +$scope.user);
                });


        console.log("the rootscope logged in user is 2" +$scope.user);
        $http.get("/mdmservice/services/entities/" +$rootScope.loggedInUser) // here rootscope is undefined and throws me 404 error not found
            .success(
                function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.entities = data;


                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
                    $scope.error = true;
                    $scope.errorMessage = "A system error occured."
                })
                .finally(function () {
                    $scope.showSpinner = false;
                });
```

Comment: Which line is it undefined?

Comment: i have given in the comments on the right side

Answer (score 1):

That happens because `$http` calls are **asynchronous** - that means your program executes in the following order:

1. start first http call
2. print console log statement
3. start second http call
4. execute the `success` or `error` callbacks once the respective http call is finished

So to make your script work you can put the `console.log` statement and your second http call within the `success` callback of the first http call.

If you have trouble understanding this, I would recommend reading up on asynchronous programming in javascript with [Callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks) and [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Answer (score 1):

That's because the first get function hasn't finished yet. You should call the second in callback of the first (in success area).